# Answer looks deleted but isn't

Tags: support, answers, design, down-votes

I have answered a question, and after some time, it looks like a deleted post (it is not deleted, but displays in faded fonts):

> [image]

Why is it doing this?

Comment: *Answers with score of -3 or lower get light gray text color and so are all comments made on such answers*

Answer (score 5):

It's greyed out - not deleted - because the score is -3 (or less).

This shows the user that the answer is not to be trusted.